# Angular 5 keyup events is fired twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

So I have a very simple app, literaly a simple hello world, on top of that I added bootstrap for the design and ng-bootstrap for the components.

In one ts file I have the following code:

```
showMeTheKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

On an html page I have the following code:

```
<input (keyup)="showMeTheKey($event)">
```

This results in two events appearing on the console whenever I press a key, the events are the same except the timestamp that is of course different (it's some microseconds differences here)

Any idea why this is happening ? Or is it normal ?

Thanks !

EDIT: To answer the comments here is my app code

Here is my app.module:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { InputModule } from './input/input.module';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    InputModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my app component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';

    showMeTheKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log(event);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}
```

And here is my app html:

```
<input (keyup)="showMeTheKey($event)">
```

EDIT 2: Here is an online demo with an editor so you can have access to the code (of course on the live demo press F12 to see the logs):

Live demo: https://angular-znlk4p.stackblitz.io

Editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znlk4p

EDIT 3: Here is a printscreen of the event firing twice in the demo
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAYiC.png)

Comment: It's not normal. The event should fired once, but we can't say anything without your code or better stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/). For now you show too less, if you have only provided code, it should work fine, but I thing that something else breaks the behavior.

Comment: Is there any chance you added the page to the stack twice? You'd only see one but both would sit there waiting to accept any key up events, meaning one key up would result in two console logs.

Comment: I just added more code @CommercialSuicide

Comment: @Steve i am literally just starting with angular, what is this stack ?

Comment: I tried to replicate it in an online code but with no success. Can you create a demo to highlight the issue?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I added a demo, it is a very nice software you just shared

Comment: @Shashank I added a demo so you can clearly see the problem :)

Comment: @OlivierAlves in provided demo the event fires only ones, isn't it?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i think you meant fires only ones ? and no in here it fires it twice, like in my program

Comment: @OlivierAlves I think your keyboard might be broken. :) It's only firing once in the Stackblitz demo.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I added a picture to prove it, and let me try with another keyboard...

Comment: @CommercialSuicide i added a picture for you to see the double event happening on the demo

Comment: Myself too unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue, in the console, it shows only one log when an event occurs once on the keyup event.

Comment: @Shashank i have found the problem I am developing through a VM ! and it appears to be a bug in the client ! thanks for the help !

Comment: @NiralMunjariya I have found the problem I am developing through a VM ! and it appears to be a bug in the client ! thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Hey all I have found my bug !

I am developing through a virtual machine ! 
And the software I am using is sending twice the keys for some reason... 
Even if I only type one letter, it is very strange...

I need report that bug to the manufacturer !

I tested my own demo on a non VM PC and it works indeed correctly !

Thank you all for helping me find this !

Cheers !